# Eee PC/Windows 7 touchpad not working?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, touchpad

When i got home the other day my Eee PC windows 7 laptop's touchpad's scroll up/down, zoom in/out functions stop working, what can i do to make it work again?

Comment: Only in Chrome, or in other applications as well? Did you try restarting Chrome or rebooting Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have disabled the touchpad scrolling. It looks like your Eee PC laptop uses Synaptics Touchpad drivers.

#### Follow these steps...

- Go to **Start**
- Select **Control Panel**
- Select the heading **Hardward and Sound**
- Under the head Devices and Printers select **Mouse**
- Select the tab **Device Settings** - (*It should have a red icon on the tab too*)
- Click to highlight **Synaptics Touchpad...** (*Right under the Devices*)
- Click on **Settings...**
- Expand **Scrolling** by click on the **[+]** next to Scrolling
- Click on **One-Finger Scrolling**
- Put a check in the check box for **Enable vertical scrolling**
- Repeat last step if you desire horizontal scrolling by checking **Enable horizontal Scholling**
- Click **Apply**
- Click **OK**
- **You are finish**

*I hope this works out. Will update my answer if more information is provide*

Answer (score 1):

Is it at all possible that you simply disabled it? On my HP, It will disable automatically when I plug in the minisensor for a wireless mouse.